# Android: Listview item not deleting. Id not being retrieved

Tags: java, android, database, listview

I am currently trying to add a deleting ability to a ListView onItemLongClick. Unfortunately, for some reason I cannot seem to do this. Whenever I long click, the dialog box appears correctly and when I press yes to delete, nothing at all happens. The item still remains in the Listview and in the database because I call the method to display all the items from the updated database right after I call my delete method. I have been trying to fix this problem for two days now and I have gotten nowhere. It seems as though it is unable to retrieve an Id from the database for each item, but I am not sure why it would be doing this.

Here is my habit object class:

```
public class Habit extends Object implements Serializable{

    private int day_count;
    private int _id;
    private String habit_name, date_started, end_date, day_count_string, id_string;

    public Habit(){
    }

    public Habit(int id, String name, String startDate, String endDate, int dayCount){
        this._id = id;
        this.habit_name = name;
        this.date_started = startDate;
        this.end_date = endDate;
        this.day_count = dayCount;
    }

    public Habit(String name, String startDate, String endDate, int dayCount){
        this.habit_name = name;
        this.date_started = startDate;
        this.end_date = endDate;
        this.day_count = dayCount;
    }

    public int getID()
    {
        return _id;
    }

    public int setID(int id)
    {
        return this._id;
    }

    public String getIDString()
    {
        id_string = "" + this._id;
        return id_string;
    }

    public int getDayCount()
    {
        return this.day_count;
    }

    public String getDayCountString()
    {
        day_count_string = "" + this.day_count;
        return day_count_string;
    }

    public int setDayCount(int dayCount)
    {
        return this.day_count;
    }

    public String getName()
    {
        return this.habit_name;
    }

    public void setName(String name)
    {
        this.habit_name = name;
    }

    public String getStartDate()
    {
        return this.date_started;
    }

    public void setStartDate(String startDate)
    {
        this.date_started = startDate;
    }

    public String getEndDate()
    {
        return this.end_date;
    }

    public void setEndDate(String endDate)
    {
        this.end_date = endDate;
    }
}
```

Here is my databaseHelper code where I call add habit to create one habit item in the database and I call deleteHabit to delete the habit at the location of the id that is in the habit object class:

```
public class HabitDbHelper extends SQLiteOpenHelper{
    private static final int DATABASE_VERSION = 1;
    private static final String DATABASE_NAME="habits";

    public static final String TABLE_HABITS = "habit_names";
    public static final String KEY_NAME = "hname";
    public static final String KEY_ID = "id";
    public static final String KEY_STARTDATE = "start_date";
    public static final String KEY_ENDDATE = "end_date";
    public static final String KEY_DAYCOUNT = "day_count";

    public HabitDbHelper(Context context) {
        super(context, DATABASE_NAME, null, DATABASE_VERSION);
    }

    // Creating Tables
    @Override
    public void onCreate(SQLiteDatabase db) {
        db.execSQL("CREATE TABLE "+TABLE_HABITS+" ("
                +KEY_ID+" INTEGER PRIMARY KEY AUTOINCREMENT, "
                +KEY_NAME+" TEXT, "
                +KEY_STARTDATE+" TEXT, "
                +KEY_ENDDATE+" TEXT, "
                +KEY_DAYCOUNT+" INTEGER);");
    }

    // Upgrading Database
    @Override
    public void onUpgrade(SQLiteDatabase db, int oldVersion, int newVersion) {
        db.execSQL("DROP TABLE IF EXISTS "+TABLE_HABITS);
        onCreate(db);
    }

    //Adding new habit
    public void addHabit(Habit habit) {
        SQLiteDatabase db = this.getWritableDatabase();

        ContentValues values = new ContentValues();
        values.put(KEY_NAME, habit.getName()); // Habit Name
        values.put(KEY_STARTDATE, habit.getStartDate()); // Start Date
        values.put(KEY_ENDDATE, habit.getEndDate()); // End Date
        values.put(KEY_DAYCOUNT, habit.getDayCount());

        // Inserting Row
        db.insert(TABLE_HABITS, null, values);
        db.close(); // Closing database connection
    }

    // Fetching 1 Habit
    public Habit getHabit(int id) {
        SQLiteDatabase db = this.getReadableDatabase();

        Cursor cursor = db.query(TABLE_HABITS, new String[] { KEY_ID,
                        KEY_NAME, KEY_STARTDATE ,KEY_ENDDATE, KEY_DAYCOUNT }, KEY_ID + "=?",
                new String[] { String.valueOf(id) }, null, null, null, null);
        if (cursor != null)
            cursor.moveToFirst();

        Habit habit = new Habit(Integer.parseInt(cursor.getString(0)), cursor.getString(1), cursor.getString(2), cursor.getString(3), Integer.parseInt(cursor.getString(4)));
        // return contact
        return habit;
    }

    // Fetching all Habits
    public ArrayList<Habit> getAllHabits() {
        ArrayList<Habit> habitList = new ArrayList<Habit>();
        // Select All Query
        String selectQuery = "SELECT  * FROM " + TABLE_HABITS;

        SQLiteDatabase db = this.getWritableDatabase();
        Cursor cursor = db.rawQuery(selectQuery, null);

        // looping through all rows and adding to list
        if (cursor.moveToFirst()) {
            do {
                Habit habit = new Habit();
                habit.setID(Integer.parseInt(cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndex(KEY_ID))));
                habit.setName(cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndex(KEY_NAME)));
                habit.setStartDate(cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndex(KEY_STARTDATE)));
                habit.setEndDate(cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndex(KEY_ENDDATE)));
                habit.setDayCount(Integer.parseInt(cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndex(KEY_DAYCOUNT))));

                // Adding contact to list
                habitList.add(habit);
            } while (cursor.moveToNext());
        }
        return habitList;
    }

    // Deleting Single Habit
    public void deleteHabit(Habit habit) {
        SQLiteDatabase db = this.getWritableDatabase();
        db.delete(TABLE_HABITS, KEY_ID + " = ?",
                new String[] { String.valueOf(habit.getID()) });
        db.close();
    }

}
```

Here is my Listview adapter where each item is put into a custom item layout:

```
public class HabitAdapter extends BaseAdapter {

    private ArrayList<Habit> habits;
    private Context context;
    private int layoutId;
    private long id1;

    public HabitAdapter(Context c, int LayoutId,ArrayList<Habit> habits) {
        this.context = c;
        this.layoutId = LayoutId;
        this.habits = habits;
    }

    @Override
    public int getCount() {
        return habits.size();
    }

    @Override
    public Habit getItem(int position) {
        return habits.get(position);
    }

    @Override
    public long getItemId(int position) {
        Habit habit = (Habit)habits.get(position);
        id1 = Long.parseLong(habit.getIDString());
        return id1;
    }

    public View getView(int pos, View child, ViewGroup parent) {
        Holder mHolder;
        LayoutInflater layoutInflater;
        Habit habit = habits.get(pos);
        if (child == null) {
            layoutInflater = (LayoutInflater) context.getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
            child = layoutInflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_start_habit_item, null);
            mHolder = new Holder();
            mHolder.title = (TextView)child.findViewById(R.id.fragment_title);
            mHolder.dayCount = (TextView)child.findViewById(R.id.fragment_days_left);
            mHolder.startDate = (TextView)child.findViewById(R.id.fragment_start_date);
            child.setTag(mHolder);
        } else {
            mHolder = (Holder) child.getTag();
        }
        mHolder.title.setText(habit.getName());
        mHolder.dayCount.setText("Days Completed: " + habit.getDayCountString());
        mHolder.startDate.setText("Date Started: " + habit.getStartDate());
        return child;
    }

    public class Holder {
        TextView title;
        TextView dayCount;
        TextView startDate;
    }

}
```

And finally, my main activity where I delete the item that is selected onItemLongClick:

```
public class fourtyMain extends Activity
{
    private HabitDbHelper               mDB;
    private ListView                    mList;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState)
    {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.fourty_main);

        mList = (ListView)findViewById(R.id.habit_list);
        mDB = new HabitDbHelper(this);

        getActionBar().setDisplayShowTitleEnabled(false);

        //Start new activity with click
        mList.setOnItemClickListener(new AdapterView.OnItemClickListener() {

            public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position, long arg3)
            {
                Intent singleI = new Intent(fourtyMain.this, SingleHabitView.class);
                final Habit habit = (Habit) parent.getAdapter().getItem(position);
                singleI.putExtra("habit", habit);
                startActivity(singleI);
            }
        });

        //long click to delete data
        mList.setOnItemLongClickListener(new AdapterView.OnItemLongClickListener() {

            public boolean onItemLongClick(AdapterView<?> parent, final View view, int position, long id) {

                final Habit habit = (Habit) parent.getAdapter().getItem(position);
                deleteHabitInListView(habit);
                return true;
            }

            private void deleteHabitInListView(final Habit habit){
                Builder deleteDialog = new AlertDialog.Builder(fourtyMain.this);
                deleteDialog.setTitle("Delete " + habit.getName() + "?");
                deleteDialog.setMessage("Are you sure you want to delete this habit? All your progress will be lost!");
                deleteDialog.setPositiveButton("Yes", new AlertDialog.OnClickListener() {
                    @Override
                    public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {
                        mDB.deleteHabit(habit);
                        displayData();
                    }
                });

                deleteDialog.setNegativeButton("No", new AlertDialog.OnClickListener() {
                    @Override
                    public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {
                        dialog.dismiss();
                    }
                });
                deleteDialog.show();
            }
        });
    }

    //Populate Listview
    @Override
    protected void onResume() {
        displayData();
        super.onResume();
    }

    private void displayData()
    {
        ArrayList<Habit> habitList = mDB.getAllHabits();

        HabitAdapter disadpt = new HabitAdapter(fourtyMain.this, R.layout.fragment_start_habit_item, habitList);
        mList.setAdapter(disadpt);
        disadpt.notifyDataSetChanged();
    }
}
```

I am absolutely lost on this one. I have been working for two days now to try and fix this problem and I have gotten nowhere. If I had to guess, I think I am going wrong on either retrieving the ID from the database or storing it incorrectly.

EDIT:
To add to this, I just found a way to write the id to a toast whenever the item is clicked. No matter what item in the list, it is returning 0 for the id. This makes me think that I am either fetching the id incorrectly or storing it incorrectly and my delete function is correct.

Comment: Are you sure that habit row got deleted from the table? please get the number of rows in the table before and after deletion and compare it.

Comment: if key is an integer data type why do you need to compare it to a string value ??? try using rawQuery incase it works..!!

Comment: @madhu that is where it is going wrong, it is not deleting at all which makes me think that it is an ID error. And rat-a-tat-a-tat-ratatouille where am I comparing it to a string value? Also where would I implement rawQuery?

Comment: @Rat-a-tat-a-tatRatatouille ^tried to tag you but could only do one at a time

Comment: change this `db.delete(TABLE_HABITS, KEY_ID + " = ?",
                new String[] { String.valueOf(habit.getID()) });` to a rawQuery, that is `String sql = "delete from table_name where key_id = " + youvalue_here` and execute it using, `db.rawQuery(sql, null);`

Comment: I just got a bit of info. I wrote this twice before getting it correct but each time it returned this error: android.database.sqlite.SQLiteException: no such table: table_name (code 1): , while compiling: delete from table_name where key_id = 0. I fixed the error quick but the thing is I tried deleting the second and third item in the listview before I corrected the error which should've returned different id's but it returned the same error, id value and all. This makes me think the id is being stored incorrectly.

Comment: replace table_name with your table_name :) .. check the answer for a better idea :)

Comment: Did that and still no deletion. I just keep thinking I'm storing the id incorrectly but I have no idea!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I managed to figure it out and of course it was the simplest error possible. In my habit object class I had it written:

```
public int setID(int id)
{
    return this._id;
}
```

When all I needed to do was change it to this:

```
public void setID(int id)
{
    this._id = id;
}
```

Stupid rookie mistake on my part but luckily thanks to trial and error by everybody I finally figured out my screw up. Thanks to anybody that helped out!

Answer (score 0):

Insted of handling listview's setOnItemLongClickListener method, handl the perticuler cell's setOnItemLongClickListener 
just like bleow :

```
public View getView(int pos, View child, ViewGroup parent) {
    Holder mHolder;
    LayoutInflater layoutInflater;
    Habit habit = habits.get(pos);
    if (child == null) {
        layoutInflater = (LayoutInflater)
        context.getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
        child = layoutInflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_start_habit_item, null);
        mHolder = new Holder();
        mHolder.llCellLayout = (LinearLayout)child.findViewById(R.id.llCellLayout);
        mHolder.title = (TextView)child.findViewById(R.id.fragment_title);
        mHolder.dayCount = (TextView)child.findViewById(R.id.fragment_days_left);
        mHolder.startDate = (TextView)child.findViewById(R.id.fragment_start_date);
        child.setTag(mHolder);
    } else {
        mHolder = (Holder) child.getTag();
    }
    mHolder.title.setText(habit.getName());
    mHolder.dayCount.setText("Days Completed: " + habit.getDayCountString());
    mHolder.startDate.setText("Date Started: " + habit.getStartDate());
    mHolder.llCellLayout.setOnItemLongClickListener(new OnItemLongClickListener(){
      //** you can get id here and write code here for delete**
   });
    return child;
}

public class Holder {
    TextView title;
    TextView dayCount;
    TextView startDate;
    LinearLayout llCellLayout; //** this is the layout of cell**


}
```

Comment: I tried doing this but I could not figure out how to add my databaseHelper to the adapter class to call the deleteHabit function. Any ideas?

Comment: HabitDbHelper dbHelper = new HabitDbHelper(context);
 dbHelper.deleteHabit(habit);

Answer (score 0):

Try to delete like below,

```
 // Deleting Single Habit

public void deleteHabit(Habit habit) {
        SQLiteDatabase  database = this.getWritableDatabase();
            {
                database.execSQL("delete from " + "TABLE_HABITS"
                        + " where KEY_ID='" + String.valueOf(habit.getID())+ "'");
            }

        database .close();
    }
```

Comment: Still nothing. Similar result to one of my comments above. Again, I messed up on the first try and it told me the id was equal to 0 for any item that I tried to delete, whether it be the first in the list or the last. Every time it seems to be returning 0 for the id and that makes me think I'm storing it incorrectly.

Answer (score 0):

### try this code for delete operation

```
public float delete(String table,String colmName,String data) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        SQLiteDatabase db=dbhlpr.getWritableDatabase();
        String[] arr={data};
        colmName=colmName+"=?";
        float res=db.delete(table, colmName,arr );
        db.close();
        return res;
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

you could try the following:

1.Either change the query to a raw query like this:

```
public void deleteHabit(Habit habit) {
    SQLiteDatabase db = this.getWritableDatabase();
    String sql = "delete from " + TABLE_HABITS + " where " 
                  + KEY_ID + "=" + habit.getID();
    db.rawQuery(sql,null);
    db.close();
}
```

2.Or you could also try this:

```
public void deleteHabit(Habit habit) {
    SQLiteDatabase db = this.getWritableDatabase();
    db.delete(TABLE_HABITS, KEY_ID+ "=" + habit.getID(), null);
    db.close();
}
```

Hope that helps!

Comment: Unfortunately, same result as you mentioned in the comments above :(. I added an edit to my main question that may help because I now have written the id to a toast whenever the item is clicked and it is returning it as a 0 no matter what item in the list is clicked.

Comment: in the getView of the adapter do you mind printing the id of the habit?? i mean loggin it?? and check if the ids are correctly fetched?? and also, declare the arraylist in the top and access habit like this: `habit = arraylist.get(position);` if at all this helps ??

Comment: Just did both. Here is what it logs for 3 items in the listview.      05-08 01:46:26.040  29811-29811/com.ryanbrooks.fourtydaysfinal.app D/Reading:﹕ Reading all habits..
05-08 01:46:26.040  29811-29811/com.ryanbrooks.fourtydaysfinal.app D/Name:﹕ Id: 0 ,Name: Test
05-08 01:46:26.040  29811-29811/com.ryanbrooks.fourtydaysfinal.app D/Name:﹕ Id: 0 ,Name: Test 2
05-08 01:46:26.040  29811-29811/com.ryanbrooks.fourtydaysfinal.app D/Name:﹕ Id: 0 ,Name: Test 3      If I am correct, Test, the first object, should have the id: 1 and test 2 should have id: 2 and so on, but they're all 0 for some reason.

Comment: try removing db.close(); after the insert line, and check again, uninstall the app and add new records and check again please.

Comment: I tried both and still the same result. I may just remove the id value from the habit object and see if it will fetch it automatically using the adapterview in onItemLongClick

Comment: if you remove the id then there is no way it would get the id .. since getId method wont work then.. try changing `Integer.parseInt(cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndex(KEY_ID)))` to `cursor.getInt(cursor.getColumnIndex(KEY_ID))`